# Cypress how to store all option texts from a <select> element?

Tags: select, dropdown, cypress

I want to store all option texts from dropdown field. Application code is

```html
<select id="regionSelect" onchange="setRegionalManagerInfo()" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Region field is required." name="RegionalInfo.RegionId" class="form-control input-validation-error">
   <option selected="selected" value="" data-regionalmanageremail="" data-regionalmanagerphonenumber="" data-regionalmanagerphonenumberextension="">— Select —</option>
   <option value="1" data-regionalmanageremail="user1@gmail.com" data-regionalmanagerphonenumber="(123) 456-7890">Region 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-regionalmanageremail="user2@gmail.com" data-regionalmanagerphonenumber="(123) 456-7890">Region 2</option>
   <option value="5" data-regionalmanageremail="user3@gmail.com" data-regionalmanagerphonenumber="">Region 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried and any errors that you faced?

Comment: store the options in what way and for what purpose?

Comment: @ArildAndreassen There is a date field in my application, when I select past date this dropdown field will show some options and when I select future date then the dropdown will show different options. I need to verify this behavior.

Comment: @AlapanDas I got this below code from Cypress gitter channel. It is returning only first option element
cy.get('select[title="Select month"]').find('option').each(function ($el, index, $list) { cy.log($el[0].label); });

Answer (score 1):

```
    let array = []
    cy.get('select option').each(($option, index )=> {
        array.push(Cypress.$($option).text())
        console.log(array[index]);               
    })
```

Is a bit simpler way to get the data. Right now this data is stored in the array, so you can access the content inside the `each` as well as outside.

Comment: The code is printing the text of first option '— Select —' for this particular select element. but when I try for another select element it is printing text of all options.

Comment: The code is working fine now. There is onchange/onblur JS in my app code which is causing the problem to get all options texts

Comment: Hi, how do you take the content of the array and store in a new fixture? The intention is to use the content of the fixture in future to compare.

Answer (score 0):

This is more easily done with a combination of `.then()` and `.map()`,

```js
cy.get('select option').then($options => {
  return  [...$options].map(option => option.innerText)
})
```